# Where can I get a large number of HTML email replies for testing?

Tags: email, html-email, test-data, email-parsing

I'd like to attempt to develop a library that parses HTML email replies. For testing, I'll need a wide range of HTML email replies (from different email clients, in different languages). What would be the best way to get a hold of this sort of test content?

I had looked at public mailing lists archives (including Google Groups) but many of these services only allow text based emails.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can always parse your own email. 

Your spam folder most probably contains a lot of HTML email from different client and different language.

Comment: Very clever idea @SharuzzamanAhmatRaslan, I'm unfortunately looking for emails which are replies and I don't see many of them in my spam box